# calling java program from Jsp on click

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page with two buttons. One is On and other one is OFF.
If I click on ON button in JSP, On click some predefined string will have to send to IP address.

How can we call Java program from JSP on click button?

Comment: Hi thanks, can u share some code if possible

Answer (score 1):

Just give the individual button elements an unique name. When pressed, the button's name is available as a request parameter the usual way like as with input elements

**E.g.**

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button 1" />
</form>
```

with

@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) 
    {
        myClass.function1();
    } 
    else 
    {
        // ???
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some-result.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

}
```

Comment: If my answer is usefull to you, will you please vote up my answer. Thanking You.

Comment: Hi aditya, Ur answer is good. but still want some help from you. I have server.java and client.java. when i click on on button, server has to start and message has to go to ip address.please give me idea..

Answer (score 0):

You can call it using Ajax . AJAX request will invoke any java program you want by sending the request to the server. see [this](http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/) for more info.

There are also other possible options you can use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) for secure transactions.

See [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for jquery ajax post . Also [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) is good example for using it with servlets.

Hope this helps !!

<sub>**side-note:** If you need any specific help , please post us the code which you are trying</sub>

Comment: Easiest form of using the AJAX is using it with jquey . will update my answer check to it

Comment: I have two programs server.java and client.java.in jsp file i need to call once i click on ON and OFF button.